# Torrent Scrape in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, tracker, torrent

i'm trying to scrape a torrent tracker for seeders and leechers using PHP.
This is the hash value returned by torcahche:     `7026AB638744F2BD2444033A8730DA146E15A886`
Following trackers come with the torrent:

```
udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce
udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80/announce
udp://tracker.ccc.de:80/announce
```

these are the methods that i have tried to get the info i need:

```
            $orig="7026AB638744F2BD2444033A8730DA146E15A886";
            $infoHash=$orig;
            $nfo='udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/scrape?hash_id='.$infoHash;
            echo '<br>'.$nfo;
            $gitsl=$this->input->get($nfo);
            print_r($gitsl);

            $infoHash=pack('H',$orig);
            $nfo='udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/scrape?hash_id='.$infoHash;
            echo '<br>'.$nfo;
            $gitsl=$this->input->get($nfo);
            print_r($gitsl);

            $infoHash=hex2bin($orig);
            $nfo='udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/scrape?hash_id='.$infoHash;
            echo '<br>'.$nfo;
            $gitsl=$this->input->get($nfo);
            print_r($gitsl);

            $infoHash='%70%26%AB%63%87%44%F2%BD%24%44%03%3A%87%30%DA%14%6E%15%A8%86% ';
            $nfo='udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/scrape?hash_id='.$infoHash;
            echo '<br>'.$nfo;
            $gitsl=$this->input->get($nfo);
            print_r($gitsl);
```

So getting nothing, the following questions have risen:

1. Is the hash provided by torchache correct?
2. Is a simple get request really all you need to get the info back?
3. Is that even how you do a get request in codeigniter?
4. Is there something wrong with the torrent file itself?

I've also tried multiple sites that allow you to manually type in hash info for a scrape, all unsucessful.

Hope somebody can help, cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert torrent info hash for scrape?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272167/how-to-convert-torrent-info-hash-for-scrape)

Comment: That torrent hash doesn't appear anywhere online besides this question. Are you *sure* it's correct?

Comment: @duskwuff By making a magnet link of the hash shows that it indeed is a working torrent. `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:7026AB638744F2BD2444033A8730DA146E15A886`

Answer (score 1):

Repeating my answer from this question: [UDP Tracker Scraping 1 script working other Not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910551/udp-tracker-scraping-1-script-working-other-not)

---

The problem is that you are sending a http-`scrape` to a UDP-tracker.
UDP-trackers uses an entirely diffrent protocol: [BEP15 - UDP Tracker Protocol for BitTorrent](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you don't to a `GET` request like that. This is how you READ the value of input.

Second, you are trying to perform a request through UDP. So you cannot just `GET` it, as the browser, or whatever, will do an HTTP request instead.

As stated in a comment in this site

> The problem with UDP is that in case of TCP you have a tunnel, inside
>   of which all data goes in both directions, but in case of UDP you send
>   the UDP packet and have to open the port to listen for the answer (if
>   it would come back). And if you get some data back, the packets can
>   return in different order - you have to deal with this too.

That's why a normal `GET` or `file_get_contents()` won't do much good for you.

You can use [stream_wrapper_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php) to implement the wrapper for the UDP request.

Additionally, you should use `$infoHash = urlencode(pack("H*", $orig))` to get the string needed to give to the tracker.